# Prefix notation calculation using fork() and pipes in C, without recursion or stack (HW)

Tags: linux, fork, pipe

I have a task to calculate Prefix notation using fork() and pipe() only.

No recursion or using stack are allowed. (This algorithms are pretty simple)

I spent 3 days with no luck. I know how fork() and pipes() works, but I can't combine them such way that it will run like recursion.

I wrote an recursion function that works fun.

```
  int poss; //global var

  int prefixNotationCalc(char tokens[30][30], int start) {
  char * token;
  poss = start;
  int op1, op2;

  token = tokens[poss];

  if (isOperator(token) == 0) {
      poss++;
      return atoi(token);
  } else {

    poss++;

    int op1 = prefixNotationCalc(tokens, poss);
    int op2 = prefixNotationCalc(tokens, poss);

    if (*token == '*') {
        return op1*op2;
    } else if (*token == '/') {
        return op1/op2;
    } else if (*token == '+') {
        return op1+op2;
    } else {
        return op1-op2;
    }      
  }
}
```

Now I try to emulate this logic with fork() and pipe(). I wrote really huge code, so I will not post it here. I just want to show you some of my logics.

I create 3 pipes, and maybe some other, this not really my problem:

```
int left_res[2]; (like op1 in recursion)
int right_res[2]; (like op2 in recursion)
int global_index[2]; (like op1 in recursion)
```

And then I have a problem. Because  difference between recursion and fork().
Recursion: When there is call for recursion, function starts from the beginning.
Fork: Where I call fork(), the child and parent continue to work from it's current position

So I think I need to do it in loop, but then I get more problems..

For examle, fro this input : + * + 2 4 5 - - 6 7 8

My logic is:

```
for () {
   main process : + operator -> left_pid = fork(); waitpid(left_pid);
   -left_pid process : * operator -> left_pid = fork(); waitpid(left_pid);
   ----left_pid process : + operator -> left_pid = fork(); waitpid(left_pid);
   -------left_pid process : 2 NOT operator -> wrote [2] to pipe;
   ----parent waited for left_pid, continue and create right_pid = fork(); waitpid(right_pid);
   ----right_pid process : 4 NOT operator -> wrote [4] to pipe;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   when left and right processes closed, I can calculate sum of left_res & right_res in their common parent.
}
```

Is my logic is right? Maybe there ain't no way to do that behaviour with forks?

It is very small part of my code:

```
   for (i = 0; i < tokensNumber; i++) {

    if (isOperator(tokens[i]) == 0) {
        /*
    Some code
    */
    } else {
        if ((childLeftId = fork()) == 0 || (childRightId = fork()) == 0) {
       /*
        Some code
        */
        } else {

            // wait for left child
            statusLeft = waitpid(childLeftId, &statusLeft, NULL);
    // wait for right child
            statusRight = waitpid(childRightId, &statusRight, NULL);

            /*
          Some code
    */

            if (*token == '*') {
                result = op1*op2;
            } else if (*token == '/') {
                result = op1/op2;
            } else if (*token == '+') {
                result = op1+op2;
            } else {
                result = op1-op2;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Is that right to run fork() in the same level with one common ELSE section for two childs?
Maybe I must use this hierarchy?

```
   for (i = 0; i < tokensNumber; i++) {

    if (isOperator(tokens[i]) == 0) {
        /*
    Some code
    */
    } else {
        if ((childLeftId = fork()) == 0) {
       /*
        Some code
        */
        } else {


            // wait for left child
            statusLeft = waitpid(childLeftId, &statusLeft, NULL);

    if ((childRightId = fork()) == 0) {
               /*
          Some code
       */
    } else {
       // wait for right child
               statusRight = waitpid(childRightId, &statusRight, NULL);
    }

            /*
          Some code
    */

            if (*token == '*') {
                result = op1*op2;
            } else if (*token == '/') {
                result = op1/op2;
            } else if (*token == '+') {
                result = op1+op2;
            } else {
                result = op1-op2;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

I tried both ways with no luck...

Comment: Since you can't use recursion or a stack, you are going to use a fork() and wait for an answer... using the process table as your stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let you get accustomed to the pseudo-code, I'll show several solutions, from the simple recursive version to the desired iterative fork+pipe version.

I assume that `gettoken()` function is defined that returns one token at a time. Polish notation is ideal for recursive evaluation:

```py
def pn_eval():
    token = gettoken()
    if token in OPERATORS: # token is an operator
        return OPERATORS[token](pn_eval(), pn_eval())
    return int(token) # token is a number
```

Where `OPERATORS` is a hashtable: token -> binop:

```py
from operator import add, floordiv, mul, sub

OPERATORS = {'*': mul,
             '/': floordiv, # keep it integer
             '+': add,
             '-': sub}
```

Usage:

```py
print(pn_eval())
```

The recursive calls can be moved to child processes that communicate results using pipes:

```py
from os import _exit, fdopen, fork, pipe

def pn_eval_fork_pipe(result_out, ischild=False):
    def return_(result):
        fdopen(result_out, 'w').write(str(result))
        (exit if not ischild else _exit)(0)

    token = gettoken()
    op = OPERATORS.get(token)
    if op is not None:
        return_(op(eval_subtree(), eval_subtree()))
    return_(int(token)) # number

def eval_subtree():
    result_in, result_out = pipe()
    if fork() == 0: # child process
        close(result_in) # unused
        pn_eval_fork_pipe(result_out, ischild=True)

    # parent process
    close(result_out) # unused
    return int(fdopen(result_in, 'r').read())
```

Usage:

```py
from sys import stdout

pn_eval_fork_pipe(stdout.fileno())
```

We can get rid of the recursion by overriding the result output pipe in child processes:

```py
from os import _exit, close, fdopen, fork, pipe

def pn_eval_fork_pipe_iter(result_out_fd):
    def return_(result, orig_fd=result_out_fd): # earlier binding
        fdopen(result_out_fd, 'w').write(str(result))
        (exit if result_out_fd is orig_fd else _exit)(0) # late binding
    getresult = lambda fd: int(fdopen(fd, 'r').read())

    while True:
        token = gettoken()
        if not token: # EOF
            break
        op = OPERATORS.get(token)
        if op is not None: # token is an operator
            arg1_fd = pipe()
            if fork() == 0: # child
                close(arg1_fd[0]) # unused
                close(result_out_fd)
                result_out_fd = arg1_fd[1] # overwrite in child
            else: # parent
                close(arg1_fd[1]) # unused
                arg1 = getresult(arg1_fd[0])
                arg2_fd = pipe()
                if fork() == 0: # child
                    close(arg2_fd[0]) # unused
                    close(result_out_fd)
                    result_out_fd = arg2_fd[1] # overwrite in child
                else: # parent
                    close(arg2_fd[1])
                    arg2 = getresult(arg2_fd[0])
                    return_(op(arg1, arg2))
        else: # number
            return_(int(token))
```

Usage:

```py
from sys import stdout

pn_eval_fork_pipe_iter(stdout.fileno())
```

Here's an example implementation of `gettoken()` in Python. It assumes that input is given via stdin:

```py
from os import close, read
from sys import stdin

def generate_tokens(r):
    buf = []
    while True:
        b = read(r, 1) # read one byte
        if not b: # EOF
            close(r)
            if buf:
               yield b''.join(buf).decode('ascii') # last token
            return
        elif not b.isspace(): # grow token
            buf.append(b)
        elif buf: # full token read
            yield b''.join(buf).decode('ascii')
            buf = []

tokens = generate_tokens(stdin.fileno())    
gettoken = lambda: next(tokens, None)
```

[Full C program](https://gist.github.com/zed/7689433).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your "logic" section.

Rewrite prefixNotationCalc() probably as

 int prefixNotationCalc(char tokens[30][30], int start, int fd[2])

You need a protocol to return your int result and new int position via the pipe.

It maybe easiest to use sprintf("%d %d")/write and read/sscanf("%d%d")?

When you call this function you have to supply the pipe
and the process to run it in (a fork for this function)
and you accept your answer (and new end position) via the pipe from the child.

Don't start by writing code.  Write pseudo code to get your algorithm straight
first.  Write it as if it was recursive but when you need the recursive
call then goto the top (or use a loop).

I think you only need one pipe because only one process is running at any time.
All the others are waiting for someone to finish.  I'm not sure if multiple
readers/writers of the pipe at diffent times might require multiple pipes, but if
you need them, just create one before forking and connect as expected. (I didn't try this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

J.F. Sebastian shows a lot of code, but maybe to understand the solution a little code would be easier.

Rewrite prefixNotationCalc() probably as

```
int prefixNotationCalc(char tokens[30][30], int start, int FD[2])
TOP:
if (isOperator...) {
   if (!fork()) goto TOP; // child does left argument
   // get left  answer and new position via pipe
   if (!fork()) goto TOP; // child does right argument
   // get right answer and new position via pipe

   // combine left and right answers with operator
} else { // not an operator
  // compute answer (non operator is a number)
}
// return answer and position via pipe
// and exit... this is your loop exit and process exit
```